# API to create/update and delete AWS Workdocs Approval workflow

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-workdocs

I am looking for the AWS Workdocs APIs to perform the below actions:

1. To create the Approval Workflow.
2. To edit the created Approval Workflow.
3. To delete the workflow.
4. To perform approval related actions.

Please find the attached screenshot for further reference, these operations I want to perform using APIs.

Thanks in Advance.[image]